# How to pad partial/corrupt TS Stream audio tracks with silence in FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have some raw TS Stream Files coming from TV recordings. These are all roughly 1h in length and 10GB in size.
There are 4 (5) different possible kinds of these

1. full Video, full Audio
2. full Video, no Audio Streams at all
3. full Video, Audio Stream ends early
4. **full Video, Audio Stream starts late**
5. full Video, Audio Stream disrupted - haven't directly
   encountered one yet

**I want to fix these up "losslessly" for further displaying or editing.**

When working with these, **#4** is giving me the most headaches.
The audio stream sets in so delayed, that FFMPEG won't even pick it up without increasing the probesize and analyzeduration.

The full command I use to batch fix up all of these now is

```
ffmpeg.exe -probesize 2147483647G -analyzeduration 2147483647G -err_detect ignore_err -i INPUT.ts -f lavfi -i anullsrc -shortest -vcodec copy -acodec flac -compression_level 12 -max_muxing_queue_size 2147483647 OUTPUT.mkv
```

(anullsrc for providing an alternative silent Audio track on Videos without Audio Streams and max_muxing_queue_size as ffmpeg would error out otherwise)

The result for case 4 is a video that is working and shows equal video and audio lengths in ffprobe. When extracting or viewing the Audio track in Audacity, the first 20 minutes are reported as dropped audio frames and the actual audio length is around 40 minutes.

**What I'm looking for is a way to correctly pad this dropped or missing audio with silence / anullsrc.**

What I tried so far is appending

```
-af aresample=async=1
```

as I've heard that it would fill up missing audio in streams with silence

and

```
-filter_complex amix=inputs=2:normalize=false
```

hoping that mixing the late audio with constant silence from anullsrc would result in an audio stream of equal length.

The result so far has always been the same exact audio track that drops audio frames for the first 20 minutes.

(While seemingly being fixed and the audio track at least being recognized now, it will still take on dropping audio frames even on further lossy reencodes.)

**Log for encoding #4 with given command**

```
[mpegts @ 000001f322d71a00] Failed to allocate buffers for seekback
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001f322e17cc0] no frame!
[mpegts @ 000001f322d71a00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 6338804940).
[mpegts @ 000001f322d71a00] DTS discontinuity in stream 0: packet 28707 with DTS 6338804940, packet 28708 with DTS 8590190192
[mpegts @ 000001f322d71a00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 15573600).
[mpegts @ 000001f322d71a00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 103910400).
Input #0, mpegts, from 'INPUT.ts':
  Duration: 07:56:50.91, start: 69474.266000, bitrate: 2649 kb/s
  Program 490
  Stream #0:0[0x21]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn
  Stream #0:1[0x22]: Audio: mp2 ([4][0][0][0] / 0x0004), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
Input #1, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
  Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp2 (native) -> flac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, matroska, to 'OUTPUT.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf60.20.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080, q=2-31, 25 fps, 50 tbr, 1k tbn
  Stream #0:1: Audio: flac ([172][241][0][0] / 0xF1AC), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
      Metadata:
        encoder         : Lavc60.36.100 flac
[mpegts @ 000001f322d71a00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 6338804940).
[in#0/mpegts @ 000001f322d7e240] corrupt input packet in stream 0
[vist#0:0/h264 @ 000001f454557e40] timestamp discontinuity (stream id=33): -25014584689, new offset= 7000
[aist#0:1/mp2 @ 000001f4bf2a3040] timestamp discontinuity (stream id=34): 25014584689, new offset= -25014577689
[vist#0:0/h264 @ 000001f454557e40] timestamp discontinuity (stream id=33): -25014591689, new offset= 14000
[aist#0:1/mp2 @ 000001f4bf2a3040] timestamp discontinuity (stream id=34): 25014591689, new offset= -25014577689
[mpegts @ 000001f322d71a00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 15573600).
[in#0/mpegts @ 000001f322d7e240] corrupt input packet in stream 0
[mpegts @ 000001f322d71a00] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 103910400).
[in#0/mpegts @ 000001f322d7e240] corrupt input packet in stream 0
[out#0/matroska @ 000001f4434f07c0] video:8958881kB audio:189875kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.011034%
size= 9149766kB time=00:59:56.33 bitrate=20842.0kbits/s speed=58.9x
```

**EDIT**:
Directly specifying the starting point 0 with aresample did the trick for late starting audio tracks.

```
-af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0
```

**Thanks [@Gyan](https://superuser.com/users/114058/gyan) for providing the correct solution**

**EDIT 2**: This unfortunately still doesn't work with audio tracks that end early (#3). For that, the apad filter has to be called additionally

**Complete command if anyone might ever come across the same problem**

```
ffmpeg.exe -probesize 2147483647G -analyzeduration 2147483647G -err_detect ignore_err -i INPUT -f lavfi -i anullsrc -shortest -vcodec copy -acodec flac -compression_level 12 -af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0,apad -max_muxing_queue_size 2147483647 OUTPUT.mkv
```

Comment: Use `-af aresample=async=1:first_pts=0`